# Is there a limit to the number of wagons a locomotive can lead?

Tags: factorio

Is there a limit to the number of wagons a locomotive can lead? If so what's this number? Is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: You can add engines to increase a longer train's speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no explicit limit. If you make the train really long, the game will slow down.

Comment: What is "really long"? Or longer trains equals slower trainer/game?

Comment: The Factorio engine has to simulate the movement of every vehicle, so if you have train that is very very long, the simulation of the movement can be noticeable to slow the game below 60 FPS. I never experimented with this, but hundreds or thousands of vehicles could probably do it, the game is not especially optimized for this, as it is not the typical performance bottleneck.